# Basic difference between Multi-scale and Multi-resolution images

Tags: image-processing, resolution, scale-space

While working on Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) I saw many research articles working on the Multi-scale images. In the literature of image processing I saw there is also Multi-resolution analysis of image which is at different level of images. Whereas in Multi-scale it seems that size of images are not changed instead it gets more blur and edges are getting more clear of the objects.

I am not using any wavelet transform. So in terms of general images how can we explain to beginners about the basic difference between Multi-scale and Multi-resolution images?

Answer (score 3):

In scale space the square of width of blurring kernel considered as the scale (variance of Gaussian and not its Standard deviation because if you sequentially blur an image with 2 Gaussian kernel variance of effective blurring kernel will be sum of variance of each kernel) but in multi-resolution analysis the resolution defined by the scaling parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The definitions behind the concepts of multiresolution or multiscale may overlap somehow, and are sometimes used interchangeably.

Let me provide the following distinction: **resolution encompasses spatial discretization, while scale relates to a more continuous framework**.

The real world can be considered as continuous, and a true  image $I(x,y)$ would have continuous spatial locations $(x,y)$. The concept of scale can then be related to  different ideas. Two of them are:

- sensors (your eyes included) have limitations, allowing them to only seize real images at a certain scale, i.e. through some blur operator.
- objects are generally distinct over a limited range of scales: take a standard paper sheet on a wooden desk: from far away, it looks like some indistinct white shape, with a close-up you see fibers. In-between, it can be interpreted as a sheet. The same happens with the desk, but since bigger, its distinctive shape remains interpretable at a distance where the sheet is not anymore.

Having a continuous image seen at different scales may help interpret its content. The notion of [scale-space representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space) is very related to this notion, and it can be [axiomatized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-space_axioms), see the works of Witkin, Koenderink or Lindeberg, and the Gaussian kernels play an important role. An image at different (Gaussian blurred) scales (hence **multiscale**) is depicted below:

[image: scale-space Szeged Haar-Riesz images]

The wikipedia entry on [Multiscale modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiscale_modeling) quotes:

> The recent surge of multiscale modeling from the smallest scale
>   (atoms) to full system level (e.g., autos) related to solid mechanics
>   that has now grown into an international multidisciplinary activity
>   was birthed from an unlikely source. Since the US Department of Energy
>   (DOE) national labs started to reduce nuclear underground tests in the
>   mid 1980s, with the last one in 1992, the idea of simulation-based
>   design and analysis concepts were birthed. Multiscale modeling was a
>   key in garnering more precise and accurate predictive tools. In
>   essence, the number of large scale systems level tests that were
>   previously used to validate a design was reduced to nothing, thus
>   warranting the increase in simulation results of the complex systems
>   for design verification and validation purposes

The concept of resolution discretizes the space: an object with a certain width can be represented by a certain sampling of the physical space, in how many pixels per width. Sampling may induces loss from the continuous space, but if the continuous image is smoothed by well-chosen kernels,  then it can be (re)sampled at lower rates. From a continuous or a originally discrete image, one can build a hierarchy of discretized versions at different resolutions (and thus size), and generally those can be used to recreate images at scales (and orientation) different from that of the original one. [Multiresolution analysis can be axiomatized as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiresolution_analysis#Definition) (as nested orthogonal projection subspace), and discrete wavelets are an avatar of those. A Gaussian pyramid is shown below, corresponding to different samplings of the above blurred images  (hence **multiresolution**):

[image: Gaussian pyramid for Szeged Haar-Riesz images]

So **multiresolution can be seen as a discretization** (invertible or not) of **some multiscale representation**. In practice however, since the data we are dealing with is always discrete, and since multiresolution can recreate a image at different scales, it happens that people use the term interchangeably.

For images, a fully referenced version of that story (for images, in 2D) is to be found at the beginning of [A Panorama on Multiscale Geometric Representations, Intertwining Spatial, Directional and Frequency Selectivity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5320) (Signal Processing, 2011).

Recently, the relationship between some wavelets schemes and deep learning has been made more explicit by S. Mallat, with [scattering networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.1513).

Additional literature:

- [Multiresolution analysis on the symmetric group](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4720-multiresolution-analysis-on-the-symmetric-group), 2012, R. Kondor
- [Generalized Gaussian scale-space axiomatics comprising linear scale-space, affine scale-space and spatio-temporal scale-space](ftp://ftp.nada.kth.se/CB/papers/Lin10-TR-KTH-CSC-CV-2010-3.pdf), 2010, T. Lindeberg
- [On the Axioms of Scale Space Theory](https://doi.org/10.1023/B:JMIV.0000024043.96722.aa), 2004, R. Duits
- [Gaussian Scale Space](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~mchung/teaching/MIA/reading/diffusion.scale.pdf), 2002, A. Kuijper
- [Discrete Scale-Space Theory and the Scale-Space](http://ftp.nada.kth.se/CVAP/reports/Lindeberg-PhD-thesis-24-May-1991.pdf), 1991, T. Lindeberg